# Conditionally setting visibility-toggling in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008 R2 that lists medications and prescriptions. The prescriptions are hidden unless you click on the medication + box to show them.

Now, in some cases, we don't have any prescriptions listed for a given medication -- they're managed by an external provider, but we want to track their existence anyway. This leaves me with the case where we still have the + box, but clicking on it shows an empty line. Is there any way to conditionalize the ability to toggle the line's visibility? Thanks.

ETA: Ok, I just figured out a partial answer to this. I had a spare textbox available, so I added the text "Show scrips" to it and made that the controlling box for the toggle, and then swapped its own visibility depending on whether there were actually scrips to show. However, this makes the borders go away, as well as the contents. Short of removing all the borders (which might be the proper solution, actually), any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/563e6d9e-c824-4719-933e-37306a3b652f) a thread that discusses this issue: you basically put the +/- into another column and show/hide that based on whether there's data.